# Call a WCF from only my silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a WCF.
I have a silverlight application.

I do not want anyone to be able to call the WCF except the Silverlight application.
I do not want to install any certificates on the client.
I do not want to hit any databases.

What would typically be the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address this using a cross domain policy file.  Silverlight cannot connect to WCF services hosted on secondary domains without the implementation of this policy file.

Here are two links to get you in the right direction
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Tim Heuer has a good writeup on the implementation of this file as well.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx

To prevent a WCF services from being accessed by other applications you will need to implement authentication of some sort [Here is a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842702/how-do-i-lock-down-a-net-4-0-wcf-data-service)

Comment: This will prevent my silverlight app from calling the wcf, but not prevent other applications from calling the wcf?

Comment: Yes that is correct I have updated my post with a little more info

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but remove the option of posting the mex of the service. That way, any other application will not know of the webservice/calls that can be made to it